# Failing to reference another model in my view asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to display Youtube videos in my landing page. I know the code works because in another view it works.

In my landing page I am referencing a model that calls my blog posts and so I cant reference another model in my landing page

The error i get says the current model doesn't contain 'GetEnumerator'. If i add another model, I get an error saying a view can only reference one model.

This is how I display my blog posts and video in the landing page with 'model ' and 'videos'.

```
  public ActionResult landing()
        {
           var model = new Stream.FeedViewModel();
           var videos = WeLove.Net.Models.Stream.YouTubeHelper.GetVideos();


            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.XmlResolver = null;
            settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore;
            settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;

            using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("https://takeonemisu.wordpress.com/feed",settings))
            {
                var feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
                foreach (var post in feed.Items.Take(3))
                {
                    model.Posts.Add(post);

                }
            }

            return View(model);
        }
```

I unfortunately can only get one to run at a time in a view.

Please help

Comment: are you wanting to pass a second model to your view?  If that is the case you can define a view model and create an instance of both of your models in it,  then pass the view model to your view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use child actions:

**Controller**

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult VideoList()
{
    var videos = // get videos;
    return PartialView(videos);
}
```

*`[ChildActionOnly]` ensures that this action can only be called as a child and not directly via a URL in the browser. If you want to serve it up at a particular URL as well, you can always remove this attribute, but then you should most likely branch over boolean values of `ControllerContext.IsChildAction` and/or `Request.IsAjaxRequest` to either return a `PartialView` or `View` as needed.*

**VideoList.cshtml**

```
@model Namespace.To.VideoModel
<ul>
    @foreach (var video in Model)
    {
        <li><a href="@video.Url">@video.Title</a></li>
    }
</ul>
```

*Obviously the partial view HTML can be whatever you want. I just made an unordered list as an example*

**Post View**

```
@Html.Action("VideoList")
```

Comment: Chris Pratt. What a champ!! So do you suggest I use partial views in scenarios of multiple models? Otherwise thanks alot man

Comment: Only when you're dealing with discrete units. A post shouldn't know or care about a list of videos that might appear in a sidebar. Child actions allow discrete units to interact on the same page. If its related, such as the comments for a post, then that should all be together on your model/view model.